# Pandas: for groups of rows where 2 or more particular columns values are exactly the same, how to assign a unique integer as a new column

Tags: python, pandas

In a Pandas dataframe, I have groups of rows where the values for 2 particular columns are exactly the same. How do I add a new column for those rows, that assigns a unique integer, starting at integer 1 (not integer 0)? Any completely unique rows also get an int.

This is a sample dataframe where the 2nd and 3rd columns will share identical values among groups of rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['plane1', '', 'az'] , ['plane2', '', 'az'] , ['plane3', 'az', ''] , ['plane4', 'az', ''] , ['plane5', 'ny', ''] , ['plane6', 'ny', ''], ['plane7', 'fl', 'fl'], ['plane8', 'fl', 'fl'], ['plane10', '', 'de'], ['plane11', '', 'de'], ['plane12', '', 'mo'], ['plane13', '', 'mo']])
```

output

```
    0   1   2
0   plane1      az
1   plane2      az
2   plane3  az  
3   plane4  az  
4   plane5  ny  
5   plane6  ny  
6   plane7  fl  fl
7   plane8  fl  fl
8   plane10     de
9   plane11     de
10  plane12     mo
11  plane13     mo
```

And this is the desired output, using a crafted example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['plane1', '', 'az', 1] , ['plane2', '', 'az', 1] , ['plane3', 'az', '', 2] , ['plane4', 'az', '', 2] , ['plane41', 'az', '', 2], ['plane5', 'ny', '', 3] , ['plane6', 'ny', '', 3], ['plane7', 'fl', 'fl', 4], ['plane8', 'fl', 'fl', 4], ['plane10', '', 'de', 5], ['plane11', '', 'de', 5], ['plane12', '', 'mo', 6], ['plane13', '', 'mo', 6]])
```

doutput

```
    0   1   2   3
0   plane1      az  1
1   plane2      az  1
2   plane3  az      2
3   plane4  az      2
4   plane41 az      2
5   plane5  ny      3
6   plane6  ny      3
7   plane7  fl  fl  4
8   plane8  fl  fl  4
9   plane10     de  5
10  plane11     de  5
11  plane12     mo  6
12  plane13     mo  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `sort=False` and `ngroup`

```
df[3] = df.groupby([1,2], sort=False).ngroup()+1

Out[1261]:
          0   1   2  3
0    plane1      az  1
1    plane2      az  1
2    plane3  az      2
3    plane4  az      2
4    plane5  ny      3
5    plane6  ny      3
6    plane7  fl  fl  4
7    plane8  fl  fl  4
8   plane10      de  5
9   plane11      de  5
10  plane12      mo  6
11  plane13      mo  6
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `factorize` after convert to `tuple`

```
df[3]=pd.factorize(df[[1,2]].apply(tuple,1))[0]+1
df
          0   1   2  3
0    plane1      az  1
1    plane2      az  1
2    plane3  az      2
3    plane4  az      2
4    plane5  ny      3
5    plane6  ny      3
6    plane7  fl  fl  4
7    plane8  fl  fl  4
8   plane10      de  5
9   plane11      de  5
10  plane12      mo  6
11  plane13      mo  6
```

Or

```
pd.factorize(df[[1,2]].replace('',' ').sum(1))[0]+1
```

Or using category with `cat.codes`

```
df[[1,2]].apply(tuple,1).astype(category).cat.codes
```

And if you just want the unique values you can check with `hash`

```
df[[1,2]].apply(tuple,1).apply(hash,1)
```